# can someone help explain the t interval in this series

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, interval-arithmetic

[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcetA.jpg)

Why do I often find the interval t in Euler's polynomial is often different, some say $|t|<π$ & some say $|t|<2π$.  Why is that, at first I thought |t|  this has no effect in the series since this Euler series departs from $\frac{1}{cos(t)}$.  Can anyone explain this?

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://ijpam.eu/contents/2012-78-1/5/5.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwirlYjO-KLyAhVfILcAHRIDBdoQFnoECAMQAg&usg=AOvVaw1I4JMEZmXWbxyYUNYSSyPv